# Two Punctuations?

Tags: interrogatives, colons

> May I go there?: I often thought, of this.

I think: I have, maybe, seen: some two punctuations, in, some, books. May you get to use this, in proper, grammatical, English grammar?

Comment: They are "points" or "punctuation marks", not "punctuations". And **every** point in the body of your question following the blockquote is superfluous except the question mark, the full stop and the comma after *proper*.

Comment: That may seem maybe strange. I think, I maybe saw this, in a, maybe, book, by a, maybe, Ph.D. writer.

Answer (score 3):

You'll see all sorts  combinations of dashes, question marks and exclamation marks  in very casual writing, but in formal writing you will find two points together only when

- a quoted passage bracketed in quotation marks is concluded with a point

  > "So there!" she said.
- a supplementary phrase bracketed in parentheses or dashes is concluded with a full stop, question mark or exclamation mark:

  > I am told—should I believe it?—that quite reputable authors disparage the use of the Oxford comma.
- a dash introducing a comment follows an assertion concluded with a question mark or exclamation mark:

  > He claims to have seen it himself? —I am dubious.

But these last two are markedly conversational, if not altogether colloquial.